# « Ils leur serre la main » ou « Ils les serre la main » ou encore « Ils serre leurs mains » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, compléments

Je crois que la dernière phrase est correcte, mais surtout j'ai un immense doute si la première ou la deuxième sont aussi correctes. Je connais la différence entre les compléments, toutefois je n'ai trouvé aucune information sur le verbe *serrer*, c'est-à-dire s’il demande un complément direct ou indirect.

Answer (score 6):

On dira selon le cas :
- ils leur serrent la main.
- ils serrent leurs mains.

- Dans « ils leur serrent la main » *leur* est un **pronom personnel complément d'objet indirect**. *Leur* est mis pour les personnes dont ils serrent la main.

  > Ils serrent la main de Pierre et Jeanne → ils leur serrent la main.

  S'ils serraient la main d'une seule personne on emploierait *lui* à la place de *leur* :

  > Ils lui serrent la main.
- Dans « ils serrent leurs mains » *leurs* est un **adjectif possessif**. Le mot sert à indiquer à qui appartiennent les mains.

Quand on emploie *serrer la main* pour exprimer un geste social (quand on rencontre ou félicite quelqu'un par exemple) on dit en général : « ils leur serrent la main », mais quand on ajoute un qualificatif aux mains on emploie de préférence la structure avec l'adjectif possessif :

> Le président s'approche des ouvriers et serre leurs mains calleuses.

Si on qualifie la façon de serrer la main on emploie aussi bien les deux :

> Le président s'approche des ouvriers et leur serre très chaleureusement la main.
>
> Le président s'approche des ouvriers et serre leurs mains très chaleureusement.

Si on veut employer *serrer la/les main(s)* au sens propre on emploie  la structure avec l'adjectif possessif :

> Le médecin serre leurs mains pour évaluer leur vitalité.

---

<strike>Ils les serrent la main</strike> n'est pas possible parce que *les* est un un pronom personnel complément d'objet direct et que la structure de la phrase appelle ici un objet indirect (l'objet direct c'est *la main*).

Comment: Mon cerveau semblait tourner autour et jongler avec les expressions _forcer la main à qqn_ et _serrer la vis à qqn_, et j'anticipais vaguement que tôt ou tard la notion de restreindre qqn se pointrait le nez parmi vos exemples. Bien sûr, rien n'est venu, mais j'ai alors dû mettre le doigt sur ce qui me taraudait l'esprit. Fascinant comme chacune de ces deux expressions signifiant la même chose ne soit qu'à un mot de cette conviviale pratique de se serrer la main.